# check customer's name in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

the customer, do I prevent the customer's name should not be the same as that already exist?
and if I can inherit the tree view mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to put a sql constraint in the code. Below is the code I have written for you.

you will need to make a module to get this done. let me know if you need further help.

```
class res_partner(osv.osv):
_inherit = "res.partner"

_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Name', size=128, required=True, select=True),
}

_sql_constraints = [
('name', 'unique (name)',
  'The name of the partner must be unique !')

]
```